# Restore an SQL database from FTP to Google Cloud

Tags: ftp, google-cloud-platform, ms-sql

I have an FTP site from a third-party vendor that updates with weekly .bak files and daily .diff files for a Microsoft SQL 2016 database. I do not have access to the original database. My eventual goal is to incorporate some of the data contained in these backups into my BigQuery data warehouse. I would like an automated way to regularly restore this database to a cloud so that I can regularly pull information from it like any other SQL database. The total size of the .bak is less than 5 GB.

I think that Google Cloud has a facility for hosting a SQL database (https://cloud.google.com/sql-server/), but this does not seem to be able to do restores directly from an FTP site. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do within the Google Cloud ecosystem?

Alternatively, I am happy to host this database as an Azure SQL database; I am just less familiar with the platform. Would I be able  schedule regular restores from an FTP site there?